# How can i get the join result using typeorm in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, nestjs, typeorm

I cannot get join result as i needed. I have two tables. One is Agency which has agency_name, the other is Cdr of which i need all data.
The thing is Cdr table has already a column named agency, so when i need to join the two tables i had to put another name, saying agency_entity.

```
@Entity()
export class Agency extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idx: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false, default: Status.UNAUTHORIZED })
  status: Status;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    name: 'role',
    length: 10,
    nullable: false,
    default: UserRole.ONHOLD,
  })
  role: UserRole;

@Column('varchar', { name: 'agency_name', length: 50, nullable: false })
  agency_name: string;

@OneToMany(() => Cdr, (cdr) => cdr.agency_entity)
  cdr: Cdr[];
```

```
@Entity()
export class Cdr extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idx: number;

  @Column({ name: 'agency_col' })
  agency: number;
@Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 32, nullable: false })
  service_id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 16, nullable: false })
  omni_code: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 32, nullable: true })
  user_id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 20, nullable: false, default: 0 })
  room_type: string;
@ManyToOne(() => Agency, (agency) => agency.cdr)
  // @JoinColumn({ name: 'agency_idx' })
  agency_entity: Agency;
```

```
async getCdrByMonth(
    agency: number,
    month: number,
    pageOptions: PaginationDto,
  ) {
const { start, end } = this.getLastMonthsRange(month)[0];
    const cdrByMonth = await this.cdrRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('cdr')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('cdr.agency_entity', 'agency')
      .select([
        'cdr.idx',
        'cdr.service_id',
        'cdr.omni_code',
        'cdr.user_id',
        'cdr.room_type',
        'cdr.audio_usage',
        'cdr.video_usage',
        'cdr.data_usage',
        'cdr.start_date',
        'cdr.end_date',
        'agency.agency_name',
      ])
      .addSelect([
        "DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cdr.start_date), '%Y-%m-01') as month_start",
      ])
      .where('cdr.start_date BETWEEN :start AND :end', { start, end })
      .orderBy('cdr.start_date', 'DESC')
      .skip(pageOptions.getOffset())
      .take(pageOptions.getLimit())
      .getRawMany();
 const total = await this.cdrRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('cdr')
      .leftJoin('cdr.agency', 'a')
      .addSelect([
        "DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cdr.start_date), '%Y-%m-01') as month_start",
        'a.agency_name',
      ])
      .where('cdr.start_date BETWEEN :start AND :end', { start, end })
      .orderBy('cdr.start_date', 'DESC')
      .getCount();
    return new Page(total, pageOptions.page, pageOptions.perPage, cdrByMonth);
  }
```

What's wrong with my sql and how can i get the result as i wanted all of cdr data + agency_name from agency table?

1. my first sql is

```
const cdrByMonth = await this.cdrRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('cdr')
      .leftJoin('cdr.agency_entity','agency')
      .addSelect([
        "DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cdr.start_date), '%Y-%m-01') as month_start",
        'agency.agency_name'
      ])
      .where('cdr.start_date BETWEEN :start AND :end', { start, end })
      .orderBy('cdr.start_date', 'DESC')
      .skip(pageOptions.getOffset())
      .take(pageOptions.getLimit())
      .getRawMany();
```

it returns null agency_name and pagination didn't work. (with join sql the pagination works fine)

2.

```
const cdrByMonth = await this.cdrRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('cdr')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('cdr.agency_entity', 'agency')
      .select([
        'cdr.idx',
        'cdr.service_id',
        'cdr.omni_code',
        'cdr.user_id',
        'cdr.room_type',
        'cdr.audio_usage',
        'cdr.video_usage',
        'cdr.data_usage',
        'cdr.start_date',
        'cdr.end_date',
        'agency.agency_name',
      ])
      .addSelect([
        "DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(cdr.start_date), '%Y-%m-01') as month_start",
      ])
      .where('cdr.start_date BETWEEN :start AND :end', { start, end })
      .orderBy('cdr.start_date', 'DESC')
      .skip(pageOptions.getOffset())
      .take(pageOptions.getLimit())
      .getRawMany();
```

it returns an error:  "Relation with property path agency in entity was not found."

3. my expecting is all of cdr data + agency_name from agency table.